# mysql with DRBD on rackspace

Tags: mysql, cloud, rackspace, drbd

I am trying to set up a failover secondary MySQL server that is a mirror of my primary MySQL server using DRBD. The problem is that I am on a rackspace cloud server and I need a second partition on both the primary and secondary servers that I will replicate with DRBD. Rackspace does not allow me to create a second partition. I am left with the default single partition. How can I mirror using DRBD?

Comment: drbd works great but use multimaster replication with haproxy in front for load balance/failover.

Answer (score 3):

Coincidently there is a blog post related to doing this by a Rackspace employee:
http://rackerhacker.com/redundant-cloud-hosting-configuration-guide/setting-up-a-redundant-database-and-caching-layer/

Comment: wow. thanks. that's hardcore. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot if you can't make add another partition or change a currently mounted partition..

My not look into [mysql replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)?

Comment: Because this is a wordpress install and all that is needed is failover. This is a very large install and didn't want to get into hyperDB because it is not compatible with w3 total cache. . .Has anyone had experience with MySQL proxy to separate read and write ? This would allow me to stay away from installation which I wasn't involved with from beginning.